# onActivityResult in Fragment is not called , when activity is finished

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult

i am having issue of onActivityResult not Called in Fragment .

**LoginContainerActivity**
on my Container Activity onActivityResult is not overridden

**LoginFragment extends BaseLoginFragment**

**BaseLoginFragment**

```
 public abstract class BaseLoginFragment extends BaseFragment{  


 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ChangeFirstLoginPasswordActivity.class); intent.putExtra(StringConstants.DATA, ApiConstants.CHANGE_TXN_PASSWORD);  this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_TRANSACTION_PASSWORD_EXPIRED);

    
    
      @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                switch (requestCode) {
       

       case REQ_CODE_TRANSACTION_PASSWORD_EXPIRED:
                        if (data.hasExtra(StringConstants.FIRST_LOGIN_PASSWORD_CHANGED) &&
                                data.getBooleanExtra(StringConstants.FIRST_LOGIN_PASSWORD_CHANGED, false)) {
                            mBiometricSetupVm.checkBiometricLoginStatus();
                        }
                        if (data.hasExtra(StringConstants.DATA) &&
                                data.getStringExtra(StringConstants.DATA).equalsIgnoreCase(ApiConstants.CHANGE_TXN_PASSWORD)) {
                            showTxnPasswordDialogAfterLoginPassword();
                        }
                        break;
```

---

**ChangeFirstLoginPasswordActivity**

> public class ChangeFirstLoginPasswordActivity extends
> FirstLoginChangePasswordActivity {

**FirstLoginChangePasswordActivity**

```
public abstract class FirstLoginChangePasswordActivity extends {
```

> private Observer loginPasswordChangeSuccessObs = apiModel
> -> {
> mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("first_login_change_password_success", new
> Bundle());
>
> ```
>     if (mBiometricSetupVm.isBiometricLoginEnabled.getValue()) {
>         mBiometricSetupVm.disableBiometricAuthentication();
>     }
>     if (getIntent().hasExtra(StringConstants.DATA)) {
>         Intent intent = new Intent();
>         intent.putExtra(StringConstants.DATA, getIntent().getStringExtra(StringConstants.DATA));
>         intent.putExtra(StringConstants.FIRST_LOGIN_PASSWORD_CHANGED, true);
>         setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
>     } else {
>         NotificationUtils.showInfo(this, apiModel.getMessage());
>         Intent intent = new Intent();
>         intent.putExtra(StringConstants.FIRST_LOGIN_PASSWORD_CHANGED, true);
>         setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
>     }
>     finish();
> };
> ```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
            android:name=".appcore.components.changepassword.login.ChangeLoginPasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

    <activity
            android:name=".components.login.login.LoginContainerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

**Everything is Fine but onActivityResult in Fragment is not Called . i am not able to figure out where i am missing . I have referred many questions in stackoverflow but not able to find out exact issue .**

Comment: Did you call `super.onActivityResult()` in the activity?

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan I hve Already tried but its not Working

Comment: in FirstLoginChangePasswordActivity is finish() method called before setResult() method? can you provide proper code for it.

Answer (score 0):

The activity you have set to `startActivityForResult()` in your intent is `ChangeFirstLoginPasswordActivity` but it looks like you're trying to get the result from `FirstLoginChangePasswordActivity`.

Comment: updated with additional Code